Automatically added runtime dependency not working in Yocto?
I Have a question about Yocto build system.
I just did the following out of curiosity:
I have two recipe.

myapp.bb: builds a simple application myapp which use share library libA.so.1.1

libprovider.bb: builds a library libA.so.1.1 which is used by myapp (To be precise, This produce libA.so.1.1 and libA.so which is symlink to libA.so.1.1)



I built libprovider first, by $ bitbake libprovider
and I manually copy libA.so.1.1 to files/ directory under where myapp.bb recipe exist, and I wrote myapp.bb like following:
...
...
SRC_URI = "file://mycode.c \
           file://myheader.h \
           file://libA.so \
           file://libA.so.1.1 \
           "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} mycode.c ${LDFLAGS} -o myapp -lA -L.
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 myapp ${D}${bindir}
}

Note that -L. option is added to gcc command for gcc to search libA.so in current working directory.
When I run $ bitbake myapp in this state, the build fails and error messeage like this:
<packagename> requires <files>, but no providers in its RDEPENDS [file-rdeps]

I know that RDEPENDS:${PN} += "libprovider" and confirmed that build succeeds when RDEPENDS:${PN} += "libprovider" is added.
But I also found in Yocto Documentation that there is  "Automatically added runtime dependencies" functionality in yocto build system.
According to the manual, I think libprovider should be added to RDEPENDS of myapp even if I don't add RDEPENDS:${PN} += "libprovider".
In tmp/pkgdata/<machine>/runtime directory, there are dependency description files of libprovider and myapp:

libprovider

...
FILESRPROVIDES: /usr/lib/libA.so.1.1:libprovider: libA.so.1.1()(64bit)
...


myapp

...
FILESRDEPENDS: /usr/bin/myapp:myapp: ... ... libA.so.1.1()(64bit) ...
...

Does anyone know why "Automatically added runtime dependencies" of Yocto is not working in this situation?

Additional note
When I added DEPENDS += "libprovider" in myapp.bb with NO RDEPENDS assignment, "Automatically added runtime dependencies" works well,
Building myapp.bb succeeds,
and final fmage contains libprovider package even though I only added IMAGE_INSTALL:append = "  myapp" in local.conf
